# Play Framework 2.2 - Ebean - ManyToMany OrderBy relationship creation date

Tags: java, playframework-2.0, ebean

I have 2 models, a workout and an exercise as follows:

```
@Entity
public class Workout extends Model {

    @Id
    public Integer id;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
    public List<Exercises> exercises;

}

@Entity
public class Exercise extends Model {

    @Id
    public Integer id;

    @ManyToMany
    public Workout workout;

}
```

When I load a workout and attempt to display it, I want the exercises to be displayed in the order that the relationship (between the workout and exercise) was created. However, the exercises are instead displayed in the order that the exercises were created. Here's a sample of the display (in case it helps):

```
<ul>
    @workout.exercises.map { exercise =>
    <li>
        @exercise.name    
    </li>
    }
</ul>
```

Any ideas on how I can achieve this? I've tried adding @OrderBy to the property definition, but this doesn't allow me to order by the relationship table fields, which would be ideal (with the addition of a created_date field on that table, as well).

Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way as far as I can tell.  Just create a getSortedExcercises() which returns the list sorted to use in the templates:

```
public List<Exercises> getSortedExcercises() {
    List<Exercises> l = new ArrayList(this. exercises);
    Collections.sort(l, new ExercisesComparator());
    return l;
}
```

Comment: Hey poornerd, thanks for the reply. While I think I understand the idea behind your suggestion, I'm having a time getting the syntax right. Possibly it was just intended as a rough outline, however, I'm not familiar with the concept behind the 'ExercisesComparator()'. I apologize for my lack of familiarity, Java and Play Framework are things I'm teaching myself on the side.

Comment: look at the example #4 on this link. Basically, you write a Comparator which determines the order between 2 Objects (in this case Exercises Objects).  The Collections.sort uses it to compare all objects in the list and put them in the desired order.  http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-object-sorting-example-comparable-and-comparator/

Comment: I see now how this might work, however, there are a few problems that I can see. 1) There isn't a field accessable from my workout object that could be used to sort them properly (as I can't access the columns in the intersection table). 2) (and this is just personal opinion) in attempting to implement your suggestion with adding custom columns in my DB, and writing custom SQL queries, it seems really messy. This is probably in part due to my ignorance re: Java and ebean, but there must be a simpler method. I appreciate your input, but will press on to hopefully find another way.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of SQL you need an order by clause to guarantee the order of the returned rows. That is the behaviour you are seeing of '... displayed in the order that the exercises were created.' ... is actual specific to your DB's convention (and not portable across DB's).

If you want SQL result ordering by 'order that the relationship (between the workout and exercise) was created' ... then what that strictly means is that you need a db column to store that on the intersection table and have the SQL order by that column.

Now, with @ManyToMany by default the generated intersection table does not have a 'When Created' column. You can either model the intersection table explicitly (change from @ManyToMany to use 2 @OneToMany etc) or manually define your intersection table with a 'When Created' column and DB triggers to populate that ... and then reference that db column in an order by clause.

Comment: Hey Rob, thanks for your reply! I'm with you for most of your suggestion. I write queries for this sort of thing exclusively in my day job, but am new to ebean (and ORM in general). I'd love to understand more about changing my ManyToMany to 2 OneToMany suggestion. I would love to just model the intersection table myself, but didn't know that was an option, and don't see much on the web about how to make this work. Thanks again!